# Search Console fetch doesn't render the bottom of a very long page. Is that a problem?

Tags: google-search-console, fetch-as-google, render

I use Google Search Console to see how the crawler sees my page with a "Fetch & Render" option.

In the results:

- Fetching tab: I can see the whole valid HTML without any errors
- Rendering tab: The top of the page renders fine, but it stops rendering at some deep scroll point

The page has 3,260 words 18,458 characters of the main content.

I validated it with v3 HTML validator and its OK, except some irrelevant errors from Yoast Breadcrumbs which do not collide with other pages.

I did check it on 7 devices so far and on four main browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Edge) and it does fully render.

If I see the whole HTML fetched, should I be worried about the full HTML not rendered in the Search Console?

Comment: Can you add some more details about how your page is coded (e.g., does it use JavaScript to load portions of the page)?

Comment: Yes, sure. It is coded and rendered with PHP, does not use javascript to load portions of the page.

Comment: It's best if you edit the question to add that and any other details you can think of. For example, it seems that you're using WordPress? Are there any other plugins that might not respond to a bot (i.e., the Googlebot is a headless server that doesn't scroll, hover-over, click on things, etc...)? Have you also tried loading the page in an online screenshot site like `Browsershots.org`? Is your page [more than 10,000 pixels](https://www.seroundtable.com/fetch-as-google-stops-at-10-000-pixels-24297.html)? If so, even though it's cut-off it will still be indexed OK.

Comment: @dan - thank you. Please publish your 10k pixels thing as an answer and I'll accept it, this is it.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to add that as an answer below and accept it when you can. You'll earn some more reputation points if you do.

Comment: Nope, you deserve it.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that, but I stopped answering questions a few years ago after becoming a moderator. If you add a little bit of detail, it's surely justified (I was just taking a guess), and might help others to know what the issue was and that it's resolved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, the [page was more than 10,000 pixels](https://www.seroundtable.com/fetch-as-google-stops-at-10-000-pixels-24297.html) and if so, even though it's cut-off it will still be indexed OK.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my experience, I'll try to make sure the rendering is perfect in order to avoid indexing problems.

You must have in mind this about Google Rendering Service:

- doesn't support WebSocket protocol.
- some interfaces and capabilities are disabled (webGL, IndexedDB , Service Worker, etc).
- declines permission requests.
- is affected by page load.

Sometimes, it just extracts the '[essential content](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/rendering)':

> Googlebot and WRS (web rendering service) continuously analyze and identify resources that don’t contribute to essential page content and may not fetch such resources. For example, reporting and error requests that don’t contribute to essential page content, and other similar types of requests are unused or unnecessary to extract essential page content.

Follow this steps in order to debug the rendering and locate the problem: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/debug-rendering

Comment: Extracting "essential content" does not seem like cutting the bottom half of the page. By the page load, do you mean page speed that I can check with pagespeed.insights tool? If so, it is good - 85% on Desktop, and I fetch as Desktop. What experience do you base on exactly?

Comment: Of course not, but it could be a mix of things and it's important to know everything that could affect the rendering. Run the debug in order to know where the problem might be. My experience is based on migrations from SSR to CSR, dynamic rendering or using prerender.io on a site with +1M indexed URLs.

Comment: You can learn what caused the problem originally by reading the comments under the question. Thanks for your input anyway, grab the upvote as it might help somebody else.

Comment: Glad you found the answer and also for letting me know what was the problem, Regards